# Prove that $\frac{2^a+1}{2^b-1}$ is not an integer

Tags: number-theory

> Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers with $a>b>2$. Prove that $\frac{2^a+1}{2^b-1}$ is not an integer.

This is equivalent to showing there always exists some power of a prime $p$ such that $2^a+1 \not \equiv 0 \pmod{p^a}$ but $2^b-1 \equiv 0 \pmod{p^a}$. How do we prove the statement from this or is there an easier way?

Comment: Note: both numbers are always uneven integers - maybe this could help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assume that $2^b-1$ is a divisor of $2^a+1$ and write $a$ as $kb+r$ with $0\leq r<b$. Then:

$$2^a+1\equiv (2^b)^k\cdot 2^r+1 \equiv 2^r+1 \pmod{(2^b-1)} $$
but since $r<b$ and $b>2$, $2^r+1$ is too small to be $\equiv 0\pmod{2^b-1}$.

Comment: The most elegant approach i would say 

Answer (score 2):

Note for this type of question is always useful to ask what how many times does the denominator *easily* go into the numerator, here we have $2^a/2^b = 2^{a-b}$, thus $$\frac{2^a + 1}{2^b -1} = \frac{2^a + 1 - 2^{a-b} (2^b - 1)}{2^b - 1} + 2^{a-b} = \frac{2^{a-b} + 1}{2^b - 1} + 2^{a-b}$$
Thus if $a > b$, then 
$$\frac{2^a + 1}{2^b -1} = \frac{2^{a-b} + 1}{2^b - 1} + \mbox{some integer}$$

And this jumps out to me as something that can be repeated.
It is easy to show that similarly for any $x$ with $x > b$, $$\frac{2^{x} + 1}{2^b - 1} = \frac{2^{x-b} + 1}{2^b - 1} + \mbox{some integer}$$

Thus we can repeat this process, "subtracting" $b$ from the power in the numerator and get
$$\frac{2^a + 1}{2^b -1} = \frac{2^{r} + 1}{2^b - 1} + \mbox{some integer}$$
where $r < b$.

The rest is just inequalities to show that this can never be equal to an integer.

Now as $r < b$, thus $r \leq b-1$, thus $2^r \leq 2^{b-1}$.
Also $2^{b-1} < 2^b - 2$, thus $2^r + 1 < 2^b + 1$, thus $$0< \frac{2^{r} + 1}{2^b - 1} < 1$$

Thus $$\frac{2^a + 1}{2^b -1} = \mbox{non integer} + \mbox{some integer}$$

Comment: Note this is mathematically equivalent to Jack D'Aurizio's succulent answer, but it is targeted at young Olympiad students who have not done congruence yet.

Comment: Succulent or succinct?  (I mean, I suppose it could be thought of as succulent, but I prefer steak, myself. <g>)

Comment: @BrianTung I meant succinct.

Answer (score 0):

if $b$ divides $a$ then $2^b - 1$ divides $2^a-1$.

We can use the Euclidean algroithm to find $q,r$ such that $a = qb + r$ with $r < b$.

$2^a+1  = (2^{qb})(2^r) + 2^r - 2^r + 1 = (2^{qb} - 1)(2^r) + 2^r + 1$

$2^b-1$ divides $(2^{qb} - 1)2^r$ leaving a remainder $2^r+1$

If $r<b$ and $b>1,  2^r + 1 < 2^b - 1$  and $2^b - 1$ cannot divide $2^r + 1$

Answer (score 0):

If $b$ is not a power of $2$, there is some odd prime $p$ dividing $b$.  Then 
$2^b-1$ is divisible by $2^p-1$.  If $q$ is a prime dividing $2^p-1$, then
the order of $2$ mod $q$, i.e. in the multiplicative group mod $q$, is $p$.  But then $2^a \ne -1 \mod q$.

This leaves the case where $b$ is a power of $2$, say $b = 2^k$, $k \ge 2$.  Now $2^b - 1$ 
 is divisible by both $3$ and $5$.  Now $2^a+1$ is divisible by $3$ iff $a$ is odd, but divisible by $5$ iff $a \equiv 2 \mod 4$.